# Is a good practice to change onsubmit attribute of the form to submit it?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I have a code like this

```
<form onsubmit="return false;" id="myform">
<input type="text" id="data"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitForm" />
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready( function() {

    var form = $('#myform');

    var result = form.find('#data').val() != "";

    if ($.data( form, 'validated' ) && result) {
        return true;
    } 
    else
        $.data( form, 'validated', false );      

    $.post( 'http://myweb/action', form.serialize(), function (data) {
        var json_result = $.parseJSON(data);
        if (result && json_result.is_valid) {
          $.data( form, 'validated', true );
          form.attr('onsubmit', 'return true;' );
          form.submit();
        } 
        else {
          alert( 'There is an error in the form data!' );
        }
    }

});
</script>
```

Is a good practice?

Comment: It's not good practice to use `onsubmit` as an element attribute at all. The code is a bit hard to make sense--this is not a complete example, right?

Comment: I suggest you to use jquery validate plugin for validation purpose.

Comment: your code logically does not make sense. the if statement runs when the document is ready and never again. if it doesn't validate at document ready, it will never validate.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI. Whatever you want to do this style

```
form.attr('onsubmit', 'return true;' );
```

is not good, because by setting `onSubmit` attribute directly you're killing other handlers that might be bound to `submit` event.

Comment: how is better? do you have an example?

Comment: I looked into your code again - could you pls explain why do you need this line (`form.attr('onsubmit', 'return true;' );`) at all?